# Display the details of only current user who is logged in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to display only the details of current user who is logged in.. I have created authentication using devise and after user is logged in.. I have created a students scaffold where user can create a student and I don't want the students created by the first user to be displayed to the second user who is logged in and the same way third user.. each users details  should be shown separately.. can any one guide me with this please? thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you should be looking at database design to come up with the answer.  Your problem relates to scoping.

Comment: the database design is normal and i am using mysql db and the attributes of users are email password password confirmation and in sudents table just student name and age.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the [associations between models](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

After that, it could look like this:

```
  @students = @user.students.all
```

where `@user = current_user`

I guess.

Edit:

To make it failsafe:

```
@students = @user.students.all if @user
```

To avoid later problems set user only when its not set by the controller e.g in a user view:

```
@user ||= current_user
```

This only sets @user to current_user when it's not already set.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do what you want to do you need to add a `user_id` field to the `students` table. Then create a `belongs_to :user` relationship on the `Student` model and a `has_many :students` relationship on the 'User' model.

When a user creates a student you should do `current_user.students.create(params[:student]` or multi part:

```
student = current_user.students.build(params[:student]
if student.save
  ...do some stuff
end
```

With that in place you can use your `current_user` to pull only the students they created with `current_user.students`

Comment: thanks a lot every one it is working fine but when i place the above code sign out is not working, it is throwing me the following error: " undefined method `students' for nil:NilClass" in students controller and in this line @students = @user.students.all, please help me

Comment: Your students controller obviously depends on having a current user like my code above shows and your original problem specified. The reason you are getting that error when you sign out is you are trying to visit the page about students without a current_user. The appropriate actions on the student controller should require authentication. This will redirect you to whatever you set as the redirection point in devise for failed authentication instead of giving an error. I think you probably need to read the devise documentation some more and probably some more on rails itself.

Answer (score 0):

Devise comes with its own set of helpers, one of which is current_user, so if i wanted to display the current users name i would just do this

```
<%= current_user.name %>
```

This makes the assumption that the name attribute is in the User Model

Check out the [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki) wiki for more info

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan):

> CanCan is an authorization library for Ruby on Rails which restricts what resources a given user is allowed to access.

Defining abilities is as simple as:

```
can :read, Student, :user_id => user.id
```

The above will give the user permission to only read student records which he owns. But you'll have to do some setup work first like adding a `user_id` column to your students table and setting this column accordingly when a user creates a student.

The [CanCan wiki](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki) is a good starting point and there are [RailsCasts covering CanCan](http://railscasts.com/episodes?search=CanCan).

Comment: Hi Stefan, I think we need to create roles as well again right! can't we write the code without creating roles?

Comment: CanCan doesn't make any assumptions about roles.

Comment: ok and i placed the same code as you told def initialize(user)    
       user ||= User.new 
        can :read, Student, :user_id => user.id  but it is not working do i need to place something in views as well?

Comment: *"it is not working"* — please be more specific.